# Repeated Measures ANOVA in R: ezANOVA Error One or more Cells missing Data

Tags: r, anova

Originally we were thinking a one-way ANOVA, but it seems like I need to do a Two-way because I have two independent variables. The session (the time that the minnow trap samples were taken) and TRAP (the individual trap (four per hole to be averaged) for each alligator hole in each macrocosm. CPUE would be the dependent variable, and then the ID column.

```
SESSION TRAP    CPUE    ID
One     M1E1    3   1
One     M1E2    0   2
One     M1E3    0   3
One     M1E4    2   4
One     M1W1    0   5
One     M1W2    0   6
One     M1W3    0   7
One     M1W4    0   8
One     M2E1    0   9
One     M2E2    0   10
One     M2E3    0   11
One     M2E4    0   12
One     M2W1    0   13
One     M2W2    1   14
One     M2W3    1   15
One M2W4    0   16
One M3E1    5   17
One M3E2    2   18
One M3E3    0   19
One M3E4    3   20
One M3W1    0   21
One M3W2    0   22
One M3W3    0   23
One M3W4    2   24
One M4E1    0   25
One M4E2    1   26
One M4E3    0   27
One M4E4    0   28
One M4W1    0   29
One M4W2    0   30
One M4W3    0   31
One M4W4    8   32
Two M4E1    23  33
Two M4E2    5   34
Two M4E3    0   35
Two     M4E4    10  36
Two     M4W1    23  37
Two     M4W2    7   38
Two     M4W3    1   39
Two     M4W4    7   40
Two     M3E1    6   41
Two     M3E2    3   42
Two     M3E3    5   43
Two     M3E4    10  44
Two     M3W1    8   45
Two     M3W2    0   46
Two     M3W3    1   47
Two     M3W4    5   48
Two     M2E1    12  49
Two     M2E2    15  50
Two     M2E3    3   51
Two     M2E4    10  52
Two     M2W1    5   53
Two     M2W2    11  54
Two     M2W3    6   55
Two     M2W4    4   56
Two     M1E1    13  57
Two     M1E2    19  58
Two     M1E3    3   59
Two     M1E4    30  60
Two     M1W1    16  61
Two     M1W2    2   62
Two     M1W3    4   63
Two     M1W4    27  64
Three   M4E1    0   65
Three   M4E2    26  66
Three   M4E3    3   67
Three   M4E4    13  68
Three   M4W1    9   69
Three   M4W2    0   70
Three   M4W3    4   71
Three   M4W4    2   72
Three   M3E1    29  73
Three   M3E2    0   74
Three   M3E3    0   75
Three   M3E4    11  76
Three   M3W1    27  77
Three   M3W2    5   78
Three   M3W3    8   79
Three   M3W4    3   80
Three   M2E1    5   81
Three   M2E2    11  82
Three   M2E3    62  83
Three   M2E4    31  84
Three   M2W1    11  85
Three   M2W2    1   86
Three   M2W3    0   87
Three   M2W4    9   88
Three   M1E1    48  89
Three   M1E2    78  90
Three   M1E3    14  91
Three   M1E4    7   92
Three   M1W1    3   93
Three   M1W2    63  94
Three   M1W3    43  95
Three   M1W4    31  96
```

I am using this command:

```
> output = ezANOVA(data = CSV.Repeated.Measures.ANOVA.Minnow._2cm.R.Data.Sheet, dv= CPUE, wid = ID, within = .(SESSION, TRAP), detailed = TRUE, type = 3)
```

I Get this error message:

> Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within =
>   within,  :    One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign()
>   to check your data.

I don't know what the exDesign() is trying to tell me either.

Comment: I don't see repeated measures for your sample units. You should explain in greater detail the design of your experiment. I think that your dataset was not correctly generated.

Comment: Ok the repeated measures is the minnow trap sample. So there are 4 minnow trap samples per hole to be averaged. There are two holes per macrocosm (one is E, and one is W). So M1E1, means the first trap in macrocosm 1, in the eastern hole. M1E2, means the 2nd trap, etc. The session indicates the time. Samples were taken at 3 different times.

Comment: I'm assuming I am not setting the data up correctly but I'm not understanding from videos and such why it is not correctly set up

Comment: Yes, so I have changed the data so that the trap number is not specified in the TRAP column (M1E (4 CPUE measurements), M1W(4 CPUE measurements) and I still get the same error message. I need to be able to decipher which hole and which macrocosm for each CPUE measurement. If the macrocosm (1, 2, 3, 4) and hole (E, W) are in separate columns, then I will not be able to compare the specific hole to the Session number correct?

Comment: Ultimately, I am trying to compare the averaged CPUE value for each hole in each macrocosm against itself through time (Session).  So in a graph, the x-axis would be session ((1, 2, 3) and the average CPPUE would be plotted for each hole in each macrocosm on the Y-axis

Comment: I have separated out all the data as you said, but I am unsure how to approach the ANOVA now, as there are now there are three IVs to consider (Session (1,2,3), Macrocosm (1,2,3,4), and TRAP (E,W).

Comment: Unfortunately, it still says one or more cells are missing data. Could it be the format (integer vs. numeric vs. factor) that's the issue?

Comment: Could it be that the ez function is automatically coercing the variables to factor, and the 0's are showing up as "N/A"?

Comment: I've checked and nothing is Na

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give a solution to your problem with `ezANOVA`. Of course, it would be necessary to know all the details of your experiment for a complete and correct answer to your question.

If I am not wrong, you wrote that minnow traps are the sample units of the experiment and repeated measures are made on these units (under different experimental conditions). Hence the IDs of the sample units are not those stored in the column `ID`; a new id variable needs to be generated.
Here is the dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(SESSION = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("One", "Three", 
"Two"), class = "factor"), TRAP = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), CPUE = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 23L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 
23L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 12L, 15L, 3L, 
10L, 5L, 11L, 6L, 4L, 13L, 19L, 3L, 30L, 16L, 2L, 4L, 27L, 0L, 
26L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 27L, 5L, 8L, 
3L, 5L, 11L, 62L, 31L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 48L, 78L, 14L, 7L, 3L, 
63L, 43L, 31L), ID = structure(1:96, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", 
"93", "94", "95", "96"), class = "factor"), MACROCOSM = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), HOLE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("E", 
"W"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("SESSION", "TRAP", "CPUE", 
"ID", "MACROCOSM", "HOLE"), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = "data.frame")
```

and here is the code that (hopefully) should show you the way for finding a solution to your problem:

```
df$MACROCOSM <- factor(substr(df$TRAP, 2, 2))
df$HOLE <- factor(substr(df$TRAP, 3, 3))
df$TRAP <- factor(substr(df$TRAP, 4, 4))

library(ez)
ezOut <- ezANOVA(data = df, 
    dv=CPUE, wid = .(TRAP), within = .(SESSION,HOLE,MACROCOSM), 
    detailed = TRUE, type = 1)
print(ezOut)

#############
$ANOVA
                  Effect DFn DFd       SSn        SSd          F           p p<.05        ges
1                SESSION   2   6 4372.5625  753.35417 17.4123780 0.003174556     * 0.30542230
2                   HOLE   1   3  276.7604   56.11458 14.7961760 0.031011624     * 0.02707856
3              MACROCOSM   3   9 2030.5313 1466.76042  4.1530939 0.041961697     * 0.16957246
4           SESSION:HOLE   2   6  216.2708   60.47917 10.7278677 0.010436491     * 0.02128617
5      SESSION:MACROCOSM   6  18 2327.6875 3995.39583  1.7477774 0.167180534       0.18968127
6         HOLE:MACROCOSM   3   9  198.6146 1070.34375  0.5566845 0.656642963       0.01958241
7 SESSION:HOLE:MACROCOSM   6  18  461.4792 2541.43750  0.5447458 0.767574519       0.04435012
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your help. I am not clear as to why I need to make a new ID column? From all the lessons I have seen, and ID column (1-96) needs to be made. But that is not the case? The df$MACROCOSM etc is that needed every time a do an ezANOVA? Does that tell R the categorization?

Comment: @Berin You need an ID column in order to identify your sample units, not an ID for all your repeated measurements. About MACROCOSM: in `ezANOVA` you need to specify all the different experimental conditions of your study and, if I am not wrong, MACROCOSM is one of the factors that identify these conditions.

Comment: I keep getting this message: Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  "HOLE" has only one level."

Comment: I categorized the data as above, I copied and pasted. I'm not sure why it thinks there's only one level?